# `dd of=/dev/rdisk4` gives `Operation not permitted` on jailbroken iOS

Tags: ios, jailbreak, entitlements, dd

I am running jailbroken iOS 13.5 on an iPad Pro 4. I would love to be able to flash firmware images onto attached USB disks with something like `sudo dd bs=1M if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/disk4` however this results in `dd: failed to open '/dev/disk4': Operation not permitted`. I imagine this is because `dd` lacks some private entitlement, but I cannot find this information documented anywhere.

What do I need to do to be able to `dd` into raw disks on jailbroken iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `com.apple.private.security.disk-device-access`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.private.security.disk-device-access</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! For others curious, the entire process to flash a USB disk with `dd` on iOS 13.5 is to use `ldid -e` and `ldid -S` to get and change the entitlements of the `dd` binary to add the one listed here, then `lsof | grep /dev/rdiskN` which will probably turn up at least a couple of `userfsd` processes, kill those PIDs with `kill`, then run the `dd` command as usual.